# Fluent NHibernate mapping using a condition

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class with a boolean property, like this:

```
public bool HasPermission { get; set; }
```

but in our database, in this column we have information in varchar, and we have values like:

"yes","y","no","n","0","1"

How can I map this values to a bool property?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, should have written this as a comment but not enough rep; have you tried **query substitutions**?

Something like

```
    <property name="query.substitutions">
        true 1, false 0, true 'y', false 'n' 
    </property>
```

should work

---

Edit after comment: as keyess has pointed out, for fluent nhibernate, something like this

```
        var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        props.Add("query.substitutions","true=1;false=0")
        props.Add("query.substitutions","true=yes;false=no")
        props.Add(...)
        var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().BuildConfiguration().AddProperties(props);
```

should work (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404991/fluentnhibernate-how-to-map-database-char-to-c-sharp-bool))

Also, [another approach may be used](https://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/) based on  ***IUserType***

Comment: OP tagged fluent, which most probably means no XML config.

Comment: Indeed, did not pay much attention. Please see ammended answer